# A Simple Clock Class in python

Tags: python

```
Class Clock:   
    def __init__(self):
        self._hours = 12
        self._minutes = 0
        self._seconds = 0

    def getHours(self):
        return self._hours

    def getMinutes(self):
        return self._minutes

    def getSeconds(self):
        return self._seconds

    def show(self):
        print "%d:%02d:%02d" % (self._hours, self._minutes, self._seconds)
```

I want to add a method to this class called setTime which takes hours, minutes, and seconds as parameters and make appropriate changes to the object’s attributes. The following code makes use of this class and the method setTime.

```
clk = Clock()
clk.setTime(12, 34, 2)
print clk.getHours()
clk.show()

    def setTime(self, hours = 12, minutes = 34, seconds = 2):
        self._hours = hours
        self._minutes = minutes
        self._seconds = seconds
```

My question is whether my setTime method is correct? Also, how to check whether my function is correct or not?

Comment: You can check whether your function is correct or not by *trying it out*. This is called testing; in this case, you can even write a [unit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) that would do the testing for you

Comment: just a small remark, the "class" keyword used in the beginning should be all lowercase ("class") and not "Class". This is probably a typo, but still, since it seems u haven't run the code yet.

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize the time in the class constructor:

```
Class Clock:   
    def __init__(self, hours, minutes, seconds):
        self._hours = hours
        self._minutes = minutes
        self._seconds = seconds
....


clk = Clock(12, 34, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks correct to me, except for two things. You might want to remove the default values; they seem unnecessary. You want to range check the values and raise `ValueError` if they're out of range.

A simple test would be to set the clock to something, then get the data back and check it; repeat for a few values. This can be automated; the `doctest` module is fairly simple to use.

EDIT:

Here's an example of using `doctest`. The tests go directly into docstrings anywhere in the module. `doctest.testmod()` looks for them and tries to run them as if they were interactive sessions. If the output isn't as expected, it says so. If all goes well, there's no output.

```
class Clock:
    """Clock

    Class that acts like a clock.

    For doctest -

    >>> c = Clock()
    >>> c.setTime(23, 59, 59)
    >>> c.show()
    23:59:59
    >>> c.getMinutes()
    59
    >>> c.setTime(0, 0, 0)
    >>> c.show()
    0:00:00

    # No range or type checking yet
    >>> c.setTime(42, 'foo', [1, 2, 3])

    # However, the print will fail
    >>> c.show()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    TypeError: int argument required

    # Another kind of error
    >>> c.setTime(foo=42)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    TypeError: setTime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'foo'

    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._hours = 12
        self._minutes = 0
        self._seconds = 0

    def getHours(self):
        return self._hours

    def getMinutes(self):
        return self._minutes

    def getSeconds(self):
        return self._seconds

    def show(self):
        print "%d:%02d:%02d" % (self._hours, self._minutes, self._seconds)

    def setTime(self, hours = 12, minutes = 34, seconds = 2):
        self._hours = hours
        self._minutes = minutes
        self._seconds = seconds

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: can you provide a module to write a test function since I have no idea how to create one?

Comment: @hkus10, we aren't here to make things for you, rather we help you make them. If you want someone to write a module for you, hire a freelancer [here](https://freelancer.com). We spend lots of time answering your questions, and we are expected to get no return. So please be understanding. If you have no idea how to create a module to write a test function, do some research. You can google it, for starters, and then you'll get **so many** results that will help you. I repeat, we aren't here to code your projects, rather to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `setTime` method is correct, however it seems odd to be setting the default hours, minutes, and seconds to such arbitrary numbers. Perhaps hours = 12, minutes = 0, and seconds = 0 would make more sense? Perhaps even doing away with the default values altogether is best.

You don't have any validation -- what if someone uses your class and accidentally sets the hours to 29?

Finally, as I mentioned in my comment, you can test your function by trying it out. Does it do the right thing in the simple case? Does it do the right thing with default values? What happens if you toss in negative seconds? What do you want to happen? These are all things you should consider when testing a method or class -- does it work in the intended case, and does it work in all the exceptional/corner cases.

For your example, you could write a simple unit test like this, using [asserts](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively):

```
def testSetTime():
    clock = Clock()
    clock.setTime(2, 18, 36)
    assert clock.getHours() == 2
    assert clock.getMinutes() == 18
    assert clock.getSeconds() == 36
```

Then you can add more tests as needed (note that each unit test should test only one thing).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Clock(object):
    def __init__(self, hour=12, minute=0, second=0, milTime=False):
        super(Clock,self).__init__()
        self.hour    = hour
        self.minute  = minute
        self.second  = second
        self.milTime = milTime  # 24-hour clock?

    @property
    def hour(self):
        return self._hour if self.milTime else ((self._hour-1) % 12)+1

    @hour.setter
    def hour(self, hour):
        self._hour = hour % 24

    @property
    def minute(self):
        return self._minute

    @minute.setter        
    def minute(self, minute):
        self._minute = minute % 60

    @property
    def second(self):
        return self._second

    @second.setter
    def second(self, second):
        self._second = second % 60

    @property
    def time(self):
        return self.hour, self.minute, self.second

    @time.setter
    def time(self, t):
        self.hour, self.minute, self.second = t

    def __str__(self):
        if self.milTime:
            return "{hr:02}:{min:02}:{sec:02}".format(hr=self.hour, min=self.minute, sec=self.second)
        else:
            ap = ("AM", "PM")[self._hour >= 12]
            return "{hr:>2}:{min:02}:{sec:02} {ap}".format(hr=self.hour, min=self.minute, sec=self.second, ap=ap)
```

then

```
c = Clock(12, 15, 10)
print c                 # -> 12:15:10 PM
c.milTime = True
print c                 # -> 12:15:10
c.hour = 9
print c                 # -> 09:15:10
c.milTime = False
print c                 # -> 9:15:10 AM
c.time = 12,34,2
print c                 # -> 12:34:02 PM
```

Getters and setters (c.getX() etc) are un-Pythonic; if some translation is needed, use class property methods (as above), otherwise access the properties directly (as with Clock.milTime).